# VB.net - How can I delete an Item in an Access Database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete an Item in my Access Database with vb.net

my code is:

```
    Dim DString As String = "DELETE * FROM studentTable WHERE ID='" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value & "'"
    Dim DCMD As New OleDbCommand(DString, con)
    DCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Fill()
```

the code is working fine, my Problem is it's not working because my "ID" Row is set to AutoIncrement. What can I do to fix??

King regards

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your SQL.  You do not need a projection (column list) for a DELETE statement.

Try removing the * such as:

`DELETE FROM studentTable WHERE ID=....`

Also you do not need to quote numeric values with the apostrophe character (I don't think it will hurt).

You might also want to consider using a parameterized query instead of embedding the value.